# Boost asio set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true)) error

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have two processes,in ubuntu 18.04，both use the same port. So, I set them reuse address.

one use socket, the code is

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &flag, sizeof(flag);
```

and other use boost::asio, the code is

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>  ins;
ins = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(io_service_);
ins->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
```

when I run the two codes together, An error occurred in one of the late running programs."Address already in use".But, when I run the one of code twice. it' ok.

Comment: The socket options aren't bit-fields. You can only set one option at a time. So `SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT` will not work as you seem to expect. And despite their similar names, `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT` do very different things. In fact, you will very likely not need `SO_REUSEPORT` at all.

Comment: By the way, after thinking a little, do you mean that you want to run *both* programs as servers, listening on the same address? Why? What problem is that supposed to solve? Sockets are generally single-point only, where only a single server listens for connections on a single endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much. your anwser solved this problem perfectly. It's wrong that I set two options. I don't need SO_REUSEPORT. But I want to know the difference between SO_REUSEPORT and SO_REUSEADDR .